# The SQL query contains a malformed ending

Tags: sql, jpa

I got the following error when the server tried to execute the SQL request.

Please, I'd like to know what is incorrect.

```
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT t FROM Trackings t GROUP BY t.dateTrackings WHERE EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT tr.dateTrackings from Trackings tr )].
```

Comment: That is JPQL, not SQL. Perhaps if you mentioned what those JPA entities are as well, and the JPA provider, and the full exception + stack trace ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention the column in the `SELECT` clause.

You cant just mention the table alias `t`

and

`WHERE` should come before `GROUP BY`.
Any condition to apply upon `GROUP BY`.. You need to use `HAVING` clause

Something like :
`SELECT t.dateTrackings, count(*) 
 FROM   Trackings t 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM Trackings tr 
               WHERE tr.dateTrackings = t.dateTrackings) 
 GROUP BY t.dateTrackings`

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken. But after correcting the request, I got a new error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started